# Critical Update Gives Error For the PRIORVALUE()

Tags: process-builder

The requirement is that we want to re-schedule an event and clone the existing event, for this we are using `PRIORVALUE()` but Process Builder gives an error due to Critical Update is activated.

> Critical Update : Check for Null Record Variables or Null Values of
>   Lookup Relationship Fields in Process and Flow Formulas

Debug Log Error:

> Could not evaluate formula for value passed to Flow New_SMS_Re_scheduling_Cancel_Flow. FlowDefId: 300210000000J2t FlowVersionId: 301210000002Nss: sfdc.formula.InvalidFieldReferenceException: Field EndDateTime does not exist. Check spelling. Reason: No SQL representation.

When we deactivate the Critical Update and try, it executes with no error.

[image]

Comment: I'd say, log a case and post on Trailblazer forum as well. Perhaps in the Release Readiness group as it has to do with a Critical Update?

Comment: Hi Charles, Thanks for the suggestion!                                                             Does anyone know the reason? or have you faced this issue?

Comment: No but if your error message says "No SQL representation" that's a pretty good sign you're dealing with a fundamental bug in the new Critical Update. The error is coming way down from the application layer and only Salesforce can fix it.

Comment: Hi Charles, Sure I'll raise this issue to salesforce.Thanks!